# Rules with require not working in YII

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, yii-extensions

My admin.php contains the following urlmanager but it doesnot work.

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>require(
              dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/starship/restfullyii/config/routes.php'
    ),
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ''=>'Site/Login',
        ''=>'Browse/Index',
    ),
),
```

It's working in my local but not working in online server it's just occur blank page.When I remove

```
'rules'=>require(
    dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/starship/restfullyii/config/routes.php'
),
```

it works perfectly  but I need this to make api for my application. Do any have idea to solve this problem.

Comment: You cannot have an array with two `'rules' => ...` values, the second value will overwrite the first, so that `require` is pointless (except, of course, the fact that it terminates the script if it cannot find the target file). That said,  make sure the path you give to `require` uses the correct upper/lower cases.

Comment: @DCoder I just tried it by removing the second array it's still not working.

Comment: So what is the error on the server? If you can answer that then you will probably know directly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If your using version 1.0 means try this

add a new class in \protected\components\

```
class URLManager extends CApplicationComponent{
    public $urlRulesPath;

    public function init()
    {        
        Yii::app()->urlManager->rules = include($this->urlRulesPath . 'url_to_rules_array.php');
        Yii::app()->urlManager->init();
    }
}
```

Then in `config\main.php` components index add one more array (customurlmanager) as like given below where class index holds the `URLManager` class present in the component directory and `urlRulesPath` is the property which is passed to that class which holds the link for the array of rules.

```
'components' => array(
        'customurlmanager' => array(
            'class' => 'URLManager',
            'urlRulesPath' => dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/dynamicurl/'
        ),
        ...
```

Then `preload` index in `config\main.php` add the `customurlmanager` component to load this before web application is created.

```
'preload' => array('log', 'customurlmanager'),
```

Then check it will add aditional rules too.

else if you are using version 1.1 means urlManager itself has a method to add rules which is named as `addRules` so based on that lets i explain

add this class in component directory

```
class ModuleUrlManager {

    static function collectRules() {

        $rule = array('test' => 'site\test', ...);


        $urlManager = Yii::app()->getUrlManager();
        $urlManager->addRules($rule);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Then in main.php config add this array in first dimension itself

```
'onBeginRequest' =>array('ModuleUrlManager', 'collectRules'),
```

where in `onBeginRequest` array first index holds class name and second holds method name